# how to predict RNN with test dataset

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sensors

i have a timeseries weather dataset for a school with multiple features. it has 28 places and i want to predict humidity data for these 28 places. i create sequence dataset for test and validation set based on hands on machine learning book, this is my code:

```
train_size = int(len(pivot_df_interpolated) \* 0.6)
val_size = int(len(pivot_df_interpolated) \* 0.2)
test_size = len(pivot_df_interpolated) - train_size - val_size
train = pivot_df_interpolated.iloc\[0 :train_size, :\]
val = pivot_df_interpolated.iloc\[train_size:train_size+val_size, :\]
test = pivot_df_interpolated.iloc\[train_size+val_size:, :\]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train)
val_data = scaler.transform(val)
test_data = scaler.transform(test)

train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
train_data.to_numpy(), # use all columns as input
targets=train_data.filter(regex='^Humidity')\[seq_length:\], `# forecast only the humidity series`
sequence_length=seq_length,
batch_size=32,
shuffle=True,
seed=42
)
seq_length = 24
val_dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
val_data.to_numpy(), # use all columns as input
targets=val_data.filter(regex='^Humidity')\[seq_length:\], `# forecast only the humidity series`
sequence_length=seq_length,
batch_size=32,
)
seq_length = 24
test_dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
test_data.to_numpy(), # use all columns as input
targets=test_data.filter(regex='^Humidity')\[seq_length:\], `# forecast only the humidity series`
sequence_length=seq_length,
batch_size=32,
)

model = tf.keras.Sequential(\[
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, input_shape=\[None, 196\]),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(28)\])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer='adam', metrics=\["RootMeanSquaredError"\])
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_root_mean_squared_error", patience=20, restore_best_weights=True)
checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("my_checkpoints",
save_weights_only=True)
history = model.fit(train_dataset,validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=100, callbacks=\[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb\])
```

> `now how can i use test dataset to predict with this model? is this code correct? i also want to compare the prediction result with actual targets in test dataset.`

```
test_loss, test_rmse = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}")
print(f"Test RMSE: {test_rmse:.4f}")
new_set = test_dataset.map(lambda X, y: X)
model_pred= model.predict(new_set)
train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
train_data.to_numpy(), # use all columns as input
targets=train_data.filter(regex='^Humidity')\[seq_length:\], 
batch_size=32,
shuffle=True,
seed=42
)
```

Comment: It would be great to state the part of your code you need help reviewing so that others can understand exactly how to help.